# Using SKAction's to call a method with a message in an object

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skaction

I'm using Sprite Kit and trying to write an animation that will send a message to an object. What I'm trying to accomplish is calling this code:

```
[self.tileSelectionManager swapSingleTileBackToNotSelected:_letterTile];
```

but by using SKActions. I first tried using a runBlock like so:

```
for (_letterTile in letterTileArray) {
    SKAction *swapToNonSelected = [SKAction runBlock:^ {
            [self.tileSelectionManager swapSingleTileBackToNotSelected:_letterTile];
        }];

    [_letterTiles runAction:swapToNonSelected];
}
```

but found when swapSingleTileBackToNotSelected fired, the _letterTile was nil. I looked into passing info into blocks, and tried writing (Lettertile *letterTile) after the ^, but I couldn't get this to work.

Then I looked at simply calling SKAction's performSelector onTarget, but I couldn't find anywhere how to call a method that wasn't in "self", much less how to account for the missing "withObject" that normal Objective-C incorporates but seems to be missing from Sprite Kit.

Can someone please tell me how I'm supposed to use an SKAction to call this method I have in my TileSelectionManager object and pass in my _letterTile?

Thanks!!

edit**

I'm accessing the _letterTile in a for loop

Comment: Can you show how you're assigning a value to _letterTile?

Comment: Also, show us where you run this action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The block will work. The problem is `_letterTile` was never assigned to a non-nil value to begin with. If it were, the block would gave retained the object and would send the original object even if you had set the variable to nil in the meantime.

Tip: set a breakpoint and look at the debugger's variables list.

Comment: Are you saying my example, sans the "(LetterTile *letterTile)" should be working code? I'm calling this action in a for loop (for _letterTile in letterTileArray) and when I take my call to the swapSingleTileBackToNonSelected out of the runBlock it retained the object just fine and everything worked. I can follow the excecution to the tileSelectionManager and it has a pointer to my object. I'll post a little more of this code in an edit, but it's strange that you think it should retain just fine. Unfortunately I have a dayjob that doesn't involve coding so I'll comment again when I get home.

Comment: By putting a breakpoint in the block and just writing a line saying _letterTile;, it comes up as nil, before it even goes into the method call. When the block runs it is definitely loosing track of my object, but you say it should retain it. Is there something I should put in ^(){?   Putting _letterTile in there says incompatible type void, LetterTile *_letterTile won't work either.

Answer (score 0):

It had to do with how I was accessing my object. Since the line

```
[self.tileSelectionManager swapSingleTileBackToNotSelected:_letterTile];
```

outside of a block fires immediately, it functioned correctly. However, since I was iterating through a for loop which carried my _letterTile, by the time the block fired it had lost track of it.

Changing the for loop to (LetterTile *tile in letterTileArray) solved my problem.